# Socket and SwingWorker doesn't work after closing the connection

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

I'm running a TCP/IP Socket, that sends a SOAP message then gets a response then read it.

The problem is with that scenario: At first everything is fine, I send a message and I get the response using the swingworker. If I close the socket, and I try to connect again, I stop the swing worker by a boolean. When I connect again, I let the thread run, but then I don't get any output from the socket when I send a SOAP Message, but when I do debugging at that time, and I step down to codes, I get a response and an output!. How come that happens ?

Here is my code:

```
protected Object doInBackground() throws Exception {

        Integer result = 1;
        while (true) {

            if (startReading && !this.server.isSocketClosed()) {
                // send the SOAP Message based on which message is selected
                SendSOAPRequestMessage();
                //Thread.sleep(5);
                String responseMessage = null;
                try {
                    // get the response from the client/server
                    responseMessage = Utils.convertStreamToString(this.server);
                    System.out.println(responseMessage);
                    // give the message without the header + and check the content length and if the header is corrupted
                    fullMsg = decoder.DecodeSoapHeader(new String(responseMessage.getBytes("UTF-8")));
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(MainWindow.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

                }


            }

        }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by _stop the worker_?

Comment: Stop the SwingWorker Thread

Comment: doesn't answer my comment, as it's the exact same ;-) Anyway, @trashgod already pointed out your (probable) error ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html#execute%28%29), "SwingWorker is only designed to be executed once." Moreover, your worker does not synchronize access to `this.server`, so external changes may not be visible to the worker's background thread. Some alternatives:

- Create a new instance of the worker for each request.
- Let the worker manage the socket.

Addendum: *For solution number one, should I create a new socket also?*

No. As noted [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html#MemoryVisibility), "A call to start on a thread *happens-before* any action in the started thread." It might be clearer to pass a reference to the socket as a constructor parameter, for [example](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/randomdata).

On the other hand, socket overhead may be irrelevant. [Profile](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/jvisualvm.html) to be sure.

Comment: How to synchronize this.server ? put a mutex ? but where?

Comment: As it's needlessly complex and too easy to get wrong, I would not pursue that course.

Comment: For solution number one, should I create a new socket also ?

Comment: +1 @Ahmed Saleh then as better alternative could be to use Runnable#Thread for managable endless loop, all output to the Swing GUI must be wrapped into invokeLater(), meaning includind thread safe methods as are append(), setText(), etc.

Comment: @trashgod The thread is working actually after closing the socket, then Why should I make a new Swing Worker thread? The problem that I don't get any response from the socket stream, but when debugging the doInBackground function, I get data!

Comment: Hard to say, but the debugger changes the environment, adding synchronization point(s) that aren't present otherwise. Better not to rely on a race.